# How to input character CR(Carriage Return) in QTextEdit?

Tags: qt

As we all know, QTextEdit can be used to input characters.
Characters input by user can be got by QTextEdit::toPlainText().
My application needs user to input character CR(Carriage Return) into QTextEdit.
Can character CR be input into QTextEdit? 
If it can, how to input it? 
And how to get it from QTextEdit?
Does QTextEdit::toPlainText() work?

By the way, my application can get character LF(Line Feed) from QTextEdit by QTextEdit::toPlainText().
Character CR can be input by pressing ctrl+M in CEdit(Edit Control) of MFC but it doesn't work for QTextEdit.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: What's the use case? I've never entered CR manually consciously in a UI, never heard of Ctrl+M and doubt that end users out there do. If you want to get CRLF instead of LF, I'd replace( "\n", "\r\n" ) on the resulting string.

Comment: yes, it is really a special case. Character CR is the end character of a string command defined in our system.

Comment: yes, as a work around, replace("\n", "\r") can be used to make my function work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think user can enter both LF and CR characters. Depending from operating system when user presses  then either LF or CR or CR LF is generated.